# Adding files to projects in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

When I create new template based .js files under a WebStorm project folder, after creating it I get a warning that the file is not part of the current project. It even has a red icon instead of the usual blue that indicates the file is part of the project.

How can I force WebStorm to recognize these .js files as part of the project?

Comment: files created in the project folder are usually a part of the project - unless the folder is marked as excluded or file/folder name matches 'ignored files' pattern (Settings | Editor | File Types, Ignore files and folders)

Comment: please can you attach screenshots that show up the issue?

Comment: I was wrong about the icons.   But I notice that the index.js has a slightly different icon than the app.js.  Here are direct url's to a couple of screenshots:
http://i163.photobucket.com/albums/t318/wb2wrf/settings.jpg
http://i163.photobucket.com/albums/t318/wb2wrf/WebstormProject.jpg